# Client-Side validation display issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, client

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I am trying to achieve client-side validation on my registration form. The goal is to when the user presses submit button, errors are set to visibility: visible. However this does not work. What is wrong with my code?

```js
function validate() {
    var errorname = document.getElementById("errorforename");
    var user_forename = document.register.user_forename;
    if (user_forename === "") {
        errorforename.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 17px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <form id="register" name="register" action="#" method="post">

    <label for="forename">Forename</label>
                <input type="text" id="forename" name="user_forename" placeholder="John" required>
                <span id="errorforename" class="error">First name is required</span>
     <button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate();">Register</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You have set your element "errorforname" in a var as "errorname" but you try to set the visibility on "errorforname". Rename your variable to "errorforname" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.register.user_forename` is the  element.  To read its value you need to add `.value`.

Comment: Awesome, I will do some research into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just append **.value** after **document.register.user_forename**,

like this,  `var user_forename = document.register.user_forename.value;`